# Put results from game into database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I've created a game using these parameters: Build a simple Roulette App - public should be able to bet any amount and either win or lose. The game is built i have an input to take bets and if they win they get double the amount they put in and I have the result of win/loss print to the dom but now i'm supposed to add to the app: casino owner should be able to log in and see the total wins / losses && how much money has been made || lost. I've used passport to take care of the login my problem is I don't know how to transfer the wins and losses from the frontend to the backend. I'm familiar with mongo and the only way I know to send data is thru forms but with this game there's no forms involved so how am I supposed to send the results to my collection?

Comment: I think adding some code would help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all calculations in your game should always happen in your backend. Frontend ist just for displaying data. Otherwise people are able to manipulate the data easily by modifiying your script. You should only send user interface informations from your frontend to your backend, like user xy has clicked on button z...etc. and handle all logcial operations there.

Use an Rest API.

Whatever technology youre using in your backend you can send data requests like Ajax Requests from your frontend.

Your game has frequent traffic between your backend and frontend OR your logic in the backend needs to contact the frontend independantly ( For example you've got a multiplayer game and youre frontend can never be sure that data in your backend changed )?

Use Websockets.